# Localhost API for TD Ameritrade

Tags: vb.net, api, localhost

I was creating an API for TD Ameritrade (my first time creating or dealing with APIs) and I needed to put in my own call back URL. I know that callback URL is where the API sends information to and i heard that I can just use my localhost API. I scoured the internet and I dont know how that would work and I was wondering if i can just use http://localhost?

Sorry if I seem like a noob because I am

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, yes.

Follow the excellent directions at
https://www.reddit.com/r/algotrading/comments/c81vzq/td_ameritrade_api_access_2019_guide/. (Even with them, I spent excessive time on trial and error!)

Since stackoverflow has a limit of 8 links in a response, and the localhost text string looks like a link, I’m showing it with the colon replaced by a semicolon, i.e., http;//localhost to reduce the link count. Sorry.

I used the Chrome browser after first trying Brave, which did not work for, possibly because of my option selections.

Go to https://developer.tdameritrade.com/user/me/apps

Add a new app using http;//localhost (delete existing app if there is one).
Copy the resulting consumer key text string (AKA client_id or OAuth User ID).

Go to https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/simple-auth-local-apps, follow instructions. Note: leading/trailing blanks were inserted by MSWord due to copy/paste of the auth code, which had to be manually deleted after wasting excessive time identifying the problem. The address string looks like:

https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&client_id=ConsumerKeyTextString%40AMER.OAUTHAP

This returns a page stating the server refused to connect, but the address bar now contains a VeryLongStringOfCharacters in the address bar:
https;//localhost/?code= VeryLongStringOfCharacters

Copy the contents of the address bar, go to https://www.urldecoder.org/, decode the above, and extract the text after “code=”.  This is your **refresh_token**

Go to: https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0, fill out the fields with

```
grant_type=authorization_code
refresh_token=<<blank>>
access_type=offline
code=RefreshTokenTextString
client_id=ConsumerKeyTextString@AMER.OAUTHAP
redirect_uri=http://localhost
```

Press SEND.

If the resulting page starts with **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**, you have succeeded.

Comment: Something has changed, these instructions don't work anymore. The resulting page is a 400 error. I have doublechecked that I have followed the instructions to the letter. The code and redirect uri are correct down to the character. All I get is ```{ "error": "invalid_grant" }```. I've been working on this for over a month now, just trying to authenticate successfully. I've tried every possible combination of variations, followed all instructions to the letter. I believe their API is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your redirect to:

`redirect_uri=https://localhost`

They may require https now and you need a colon instead of a semicolon.  Everything looks correct.  This process generally takes me more then one attempt, and 15 minutes to an hour to get my refresh token squared away every 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

dont use @AMER.OAUTHAP in client_id

Comment: This doesn't really appear to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you generate a new code and based on that try to get a new access token. it should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).